# How to determine an unknown quantum gate if we know all other gates in the circuit and the inputs and outputs?

Tags: quantum-gate

[image]

Suppose we have a quantum circuit like this. All the gates are known except for one. For any input of q[0] and q[1], we know the corresponding output. I have provided the output state for four different input state which forms a basis .
How can we know that which gate is the unknown gate?
[image]
How to solve these types of problems?

Comment: Please refrain from posting one question several times (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30027/quantum-circuit-with-one-unknown-gate). Rather edit the former question.

Comment: That question was more general one. I couldn't work out the input state in this question. The answer on this question gives me the way of how to solve the question effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of a circuit can be explained by matrix-vector multiplications.

If you start with a state $\vec{q}$ and if the gates in your figure are represented by the matrices $A$, $B$, and $U$ (where $U$ is the unknown), then the output will be given by $\vec{q_f} = ABU\vec{q}$.

The $AB$ factor can be replaced by a single matrix called $C$, and with symbolic computation (a.k.a computer algebra) you can combine $U$ and $C$ too.

Let's try this, assuming that your "controlled **note**" get is just what others usually call "controlled not"  or CNOT. Then we have:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\tag{1}
$$

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\tag{2}
$$

$$
U = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l \\  m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix},\tag{3}
$$

$$
\vec{q} = \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix},\tag{4}
$$

and

$$
\vec{q}_f = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix}.\tag{5}
$$

This would mean that we have:

$$\tag{6}
 \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l \\  m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
$$\tag{7}
 \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l \\  m & n & o & p \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \\ 0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f  \\ b \\ j \\  n \end{bmatrix}.\tag{8}
$$

You now have found 4 out of 16 unknown variables. You can do the same for the other 3 scenarios to get the other 4x3 = 12 unkown variables. You can use [this matrix-vector multplier to make the computations easier](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%261%260%260%5C%5C%20%201%260%260%260%5C%5C%20%200%260%261%260%5C%5C%20%200%260%260%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Ccdot%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Da%26b%26c%26d%5C%5C%20%20%20e%26f%26g%26h%5C%5C%20%20%20i%26j%26k%26l%5C%5C%20%20%20m%26n%26o%26p%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Ccdot%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%5C%5C%201%5C%5C%200%5C%5C%200%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D?or=input).

Comment: How do you form the matrix B? I guess it represents Pauli X matrix. But isn't pauli X a 2*2 matrix

Comment: B is the "left Kronecker product" of the identity matrix and the X gate, so in MATLAB/Octave it would be `kron(eye(2),[0 1; 1 0 ])`.

Comment: So it's like extending X gate to a 4*4 matrix having the same effect?

Comment: Precisely. The identity matrix is happening to qubit 1, and the X matrix is happening to qubit 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That clears my confusion

Comment: Also is there any other way of solving such questions ?

Comment: Any method for solving such problems will be mathematically equivalent to this one, and boil down to the same thing. Instead of maxing the unknown matrix variables = a,b,c,d,e,f,..., you could instead write the unknown matrix as a "paulinomial" as explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11924/2293) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2234/2293) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18622/2293). Don't forget to click the checkmark under the answer's score if it answered what you were asking.